# Select part of values in column with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written sql query:

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  type, 
  value
FROM my.data
```

I want however to get not full values in column value, but only first 40 symbols(or if its less than 40 symbols in it all). How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want string function `left()`?

```
SELECT date, type, left(value, 40) as value
FROM my.data
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string, you can use `left()`:

```
SELECT date, type, LEFT(value, 40)
FROM my.data
```